# sonata admin bundle for an entity with keywords columns

Tags: sql, symfony, orm, sonata-admin

i used sonata admin bundle to generate a back office for an entity that have two columns with sql keywords : `from` and `to` , all forms and entities are well generated and all works fine except for adding new entity cos the sql generated cannot accept `from` and `to` as syntax in insert sql.

is there a way to avoid this problem without changing the columns names ?

here is the mapping

```
 /**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="`from`", type="datetime", nullable=false)
 */
private $from;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="`to`", type="datetime", nullable=false)
 */
private $to;
```

and here is a snippet code from configureFormFields method

```
        ->add('from', 'datetime', array('label' => 'du'))
        ->add('to', 'datetime', array('label' => 'au'))
```

the error :

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO event (titre, ville, description, from, to, lat, lng, adresse, total, votes, isActive, refsouscategorie) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["dfdfdf", "titre", "dfdfdf", "2009-01-01 00:00:00", "2009-01-01 00:00:00", "0", "0", "dddfgsgs", 0, 0, 1, 1]:
```

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from, to, lat, lng, adresse, total, votes, isActive, refsouscategorie) VALUES ('' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

If you are using doctrine with symfony you can escape them by using back-ticks around your column names like in your entity

```
/**
 * YourEntity
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="your_table")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class YourEntity
{

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="`to`", type="string", length=25)
 */
private $to;


/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="`from`", type="string", length=25)
 */
private $from;

}
```

---

> Note its better if you can alter your schema and entity definition to change the names of that column to prevent from usage of reserved keywords
>
> Identifier Quoting does not work for join column names or discriminator column names unless you are using a custom QuoteStrategy.

### [`Quoting Reserved Words`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#quoting-reserved-words)

Comment: i have tried this solution but i still get the same error

Comment: can you provide error details ? also are you using annotations for mappings ? or xml/yaml etc ?

Comment: @leonidas79 Have you cleared cache ? and also make sure you update the right entity

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid i cleared cach and i'm sure i updated the right entity but i still get the same error

Comment: here is the error 
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO event (titre, ville, description, from, to, lat, lng, adresse, total, votes, isActive, refsouscategorie) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["dsfsdf", "titre", "dfsdf dfsdfsdf", "2009-01-01 00:00:00", "2009-01-01 00:00:00", "0", "0", "sdfsdf sdsdf", 0, 0, 1, 1]:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from, to, lat, lng, adresse, total, votes, isActive, refsouscategorie) VALUES ('' at line 1 `

Comment: @leonidas79 unfortunatelyi can't tell you the reason why its not quoting but i guess [*this pull*](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/pull/302) will work for your regards

Comment: Just a blind guess, but maybe 'titre' is a TYPO and thats what causing the error?...